# Disable "There is no schema defined for this pom.xml."

Tags: eclipse, maven

How do I **DISABLE** this Eclipse warning:

```
There is no schema defined for this pom.xml.
```

to keep the noise in Eclipse to a minimum without changing the checked-in artifacts (pom.xml, *.java, etc.)? Compiling the projects via Maven in a shell does not present these warnings.

Several large projects have policies against IDE-specific "fixes", so question is: how can I disable this IDE-specific warning? "Fixes" for the warnings are not allowed, e.g., [adding the schema definition to each pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37489985/how-to-fix-this-maven-warning-on-eclipse-there-is-no-schema-defined-for-this-p) or [adding a section to a parent pom file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040788/how-to-eliminate-the-maven-enforcer-plugin-goal-enforce-is-ignored-by-m2e). This question is about disabling these warning, not about the "correctness" of policies like this.

I **should** be able to configure these IDE-specific tools **in the IDE** but the Maven Errors/Warnings section in Eclipse has just five (!) settings to twiddle and none cover these particular warnings. But surely there must be a little configuration file (or two) somewhere where I can customize away these warnings, right?!? There is a promising looking file

```
.settings/org.eclipse.m2e.core.prefs
```

in the project directory of each imported project but I don't know what, if any, magic to throw in there to do what I want. There is also a promising looking directory in the parent directory

```
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.core/
```

but, again, it's not clear what needs to be done. Has anyone found a way to disable these warnings in Eclipse?

Comment: If you disable in _Project > Properties: Builders_ the _Maven Project Builder_, delete the warnings and do _Project > Clean..._ at least the first warning will not come back and probably also the other warning. But this will limit the Maven support to the _Maven POM Edtior_ and the possibility to launch POM files. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: In the _Problems_ view you have to delete the warnings. If the _Maven Project Builder_ is disabled, the problems managed by this builder remain unchanged when cleaning the project.

Comment: It works for me in 2018-12 (4.10) which is the latest version. 2019-03 (4.11) will be released next week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @howlger commented, if the project does not need the Maven builder the warning can be removed permanently by disabling the Maven builder in Eclipse:

```
Project
  Properties
    Builders 
      Maven Project Builder <-- uncheck this
```

Then delete the warning in the Problems pane. Then a clean rebuild.